# Print characters which come before the fifth <br> in php string

Tags: php, codeigniter, explode, substr

I need to print characters which come before the fifth `<br>` in a PHP string.

e.g. The string is:

```
A silly young Cricket <br> 
Accustomed to sing  <br><br> 
Through warm sunny weather <br>
of winter summer and spring <br><br>
Now that you forget the poem<br>
having memorised it 18 years back in school<br><br>
```

Out of above string I want to print the characters which come before the fifth `<br>`. The output should be:

```
A silly young Cricket <br>  Accustomed to sing  <br><br>  Through warm sunny weather <br> of winter summer and spring
```

I tried as below but it prints only the first line and does not work as required

```
<?php
$trer = 'the above string in example';
$arrdr = explode("<br>", $trer, 5);
$pichka = array_shift($arrdr);
echo $pichka; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot guarantee there will always be exactly 5 occurrences of `<br>` in your string, here's a more flexible non-regex solution which will give you everything up to a possible 5 occurrences:

```
$split = array_map(function ($part) {
    return implode('<br>', $part);
}, array_chunk(explode('<br>', $str), 5));
$output = array_shift($split);
```

It's not clear if you want to keep any trailing `<br>` occurrences if there are less than 5, but if you want to always end the string before a `<br>` you can ensure they get removed by adding a final line:

```
$output = preg_replace('/(<br>)+$/s', '', $output);
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked, though I could not understand what is the variable "$part" in the script you gave, I just used it as is and it worked for me

Comment: @Kitty It's just an argument that gets passed into the function, you don't need to worry about it - it's not usable anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

One regex approach would be to use lazy dot to cautiously match across only the first five `<br>` tags:

```
$input = "A silly young Cricket <br> \nAccustomed to sing  <br><br> \nThrough warm sunny weather <br>\nof winter summer and spring <br><br>\nNow that you forget the poem<br>\nhaving memorised it 18 years back in school<br><br>";
preg_match("/^.*?<br>.*?<br>.*?<br>.*?<br>.*?(?=<br>)/s", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

This prints:

```
A silly young Cricket <br> 
Accustomed to sing  <br><br> 
Through warm sunny weather <br>
of winter summer and spring
```

Note that in the regex pattern I use the `/s` switch to match using dot all mode, so that `.*` matches across newlines.

Comment: I don't think this works if there aren't 5 `<br>` tags, and I think OP wants to exclude the 5th `<br>` from the match.

Comment: @Horsie I am assuming that the OP would always expect at least five `<br>` tags.  As for your other point, I agree, and have edited my answer.

Comment: You can condense the regex with `/^(.*?<br>){4}.*?(?=<br>)/s`

Answer (score -1):

as i see in your string you have two br tag in some lines and in explode you splited string with it and this maybe make problem for you

try this and let me know the result:

```
$string = 'A silly young Cricket <br> 
Accustomed to sing  <br><br> 
Through warm sunny weather <br>
of winter summer and spring <br><br>
Now that you forget the poem<br>
having memorised it 18 years back in school<br><br>';

$needles = explode(chr(10), $needles, 5);

print_r($needles);
```

the "chr(10)" function return the \n character. you can use \n directly

Comment: it did not work, Something might be missing 
The solution from BadHorsie worked fine, Thankyou!